# Average Rate of Change of Functions

Tags: slope

[image]

In here to find out the average rate of change -5 and 2 were used. But I'm wondering why, because in the interval these aren't included. Wouldn't it only be correct using -5 and -2 to solve the problem if the interval was -5<=x<=-2?

Comment: Ask yourself what difference it would make. $x$ is real.

Comment: still didn't get

Comment: @YvesDaoust You mean it wouldn't make any difference?

Comment: What would be your answers with $<$ and with $\le$ ?

Comment: the same? but  < and <= aren't the same, are they?

Comment: What would be your answers ?

Comment: okay, the same -2. but I was told that I need to be careful with < and <= especially with intervals.

Comment: In this particular case, $-5$ and $-5+\epsilon$ don't make a difference.

Comment: I got it bro, thanx

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume that the real-valued function $y(x)$ is continuous on $[-5,-2]$ and differentiable on $(-5,-2)$. If so, we can apply the Mean Value Theorem (MVT or LMVT) and find the average rate of change of $y(x)$ over the interval $-5\le x\le-2$ as equal to the slope of the tangent line at some point $c\in(-5,-2)$ that is guaranteed to exist.
$$y'(c)=\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}=\frac{y(-2)-y(-5)}{-2-(-5)}=\frac{0-6}{-2+5}=\frac{-6}{3}=-2$$
In regards to your comment, the inequality symbols $\lt$ and $\le$ are not the same. You are right to be mindful of the applicability of certain statements and theorems on certain intervals, but we are permitted to apply the MVT here in this problem. Also, because we assumed that $y(x)$ is continuous at $x=-2$, we assumed the quintessential requirement for continuity at $x=-2$.
$$\lim\limits_{x\to-2}(y(x))=y(-2)=0$$
The left-side and right-side limits must be equal for the ordinary limit to exist, and $x\to-2^-$ implies $x\lt-2$. The same reasoning can be said for $x=-5$, particularly $x\to-5^+$ meaning $x\gt-5$. Thus, if you want to be particularly meticulous, the average rate of change of $y(x)$ on $(-5,-2)$, the interval in the problem, approaches the same amount as on $[-5,-2]$ as we established, all things considered.